# How to exclude certains columns while using eloquent | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have an group table. My main table. So i have group_hotels table this table is a pivot table. (id, group_id, hotel_id)

Now in my blade group edit page, i want to list before added pivot table like this code:
My Group model:

```
public function hotels(){
    return $this ->belongsToMany('App\Models\Hotel','group_hotels');
}
```

My controller:

```
$group = Group::find($id);
$hotels=Hotel::all();
```

My blade hotel select2 field:

```
@foreach($hotels as $hotel)
   <option value="{{$hotel->id}}">{{$hotel->name}}</option>
     @foreach ($group->hotels as $item)
       <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

The output like this: http://prntscr.com/10v13ed

Now what i want to do, in my group_hotels pivot table, if hotel id exist in group_hotels except the in the pivot table id nothing come hotel table.

In short: If the hotel_id part in the group_hotels table is present in my hotel table, I do not want to call it in the hotel variable.

Comment: this is a bit hard to understand what you are actually asking for here ... you want to iterate all the hotels but if the current iterated hotel is in the current groups hotel list exclude it from your output (don't make it a select option)?

Comment: @lagbox if group_hotels pivot table has a hotel_id is relationship is ok, i want to exclude this the relationship hotel id in hotel table.

Comment: `Hotel::whereKeyNot($group->hotels->pluck('id'))->get()`  you could try something like that potentially, exclude them at the query level instead?   or if you have the 2 collections you can do an intersect between them

Comment: that was exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to exclude the Hotel's you don't want in your list at the query level:

```
Hotel::whereNotKey($group->hotels->modelKeys())->get();
```

Comment: My fault, no you already do it this answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @vedat you mean if you have the 2 collections? you could do a 'diff' actually between them to get only the difference between the 2, but that would mean loading both those collections to just filter one down basically